# tau prolog existence_error on tutorial example

Tags: prolog, tau-prolog

I am following the [tau-prolog](http://tau-prolog.org/manual/a-simple-tutorial) tutorial, and I run into this error:

```
throw(error(existence_error(procedure,/(fruits_in,2)),/(top_level,0)))
```

My index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, Tau Prolog!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="tau-prolog.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.js is

```
let session = pl.create();
session.consult("                   \
    % load lists module                          \
    :- use_module(library(lists)).               \
                                                 \
    % fruit/1                                    \
    fruit(apple). fruit(pear). fruit(banana).    \
                                                 \
    % fruits_in/2                                \
    fruits_in(Xs, X) :- member(X, Xs), fruit(X). \
", {
    success: () => { console.log("success") },
    error: (err) => { console.log('error: ', err); }
});

session.query("fruits_in([carrot, apple, banana, broccoli], X).", {
    success: (goal) => { console.log('Query success. Goal: ', goal) },
    error: (err) => { console.log('error: ', err) }
});

session.answer({
    success: (answer) => {
        console.log(answer); // {X/apple}
        session.answer({
            success: (answer) => {
                console.log(answer); // {X/banana}
            },
            error: (err) => { console.log(`answer error: ${err}`) },
            fail: () => { console.log('no more answers') },
            limit: () => { console.log('limit') }
        });
    },
    error: (err) => { console.log(`answer error: ${err}`) },
    fail: () => { console.log('no more answers') },
    limit: () => { console.log('limit') }
})
```

and the console output is

[image: here]

I am not sure where to go from here, and I'd be grateful for someone pointing out the beginner's error I've made!

*** UPDATE

If I change the `session.consult` from using `"` and `\`, to using the new `` template string syntax, this code works!

new session.consult:

```
session.consult(`
    % load lists module 
    :- use_module(library(lists)).     
                                                 
    % fruit/1                                    
    fruit(apple). fruit(pear). fruit(banana).    
                                                 
    % fruits_in/2                                
    fruits_in(Xs, X) :- member(X, Xs), fruit(X). 
`, {
    success: () => { console.log("success") },
    error: (err) => { console.log('error: ', err); }
});
```

So the **new** question is: "Why does that make a difference?"

Thanks - again!

Answer (score 0):

OK - the process is asynchronous, and `answer` needs to execute after `query` which needs to execute after `consult`, so nested function calls.

It's in the docs... sigh.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118287/using-await-and-async-to-make-load-an-parse-tau-prolog-before-anything-else) SO post covered it. Sorry for wasting folks' time.